# Add an expression at the start of every log file using Logback

Tags: java, logging, logback

I have a project which has multiple modules. and every module has its own logback.xml. Their appender is rolling files. How can I add a specific expression at the start of every output log file?

Comment: Could you show us your current logback configuration and also clarify what this means: "add a specific expression at the start of every output log file"? (An example might help).

Comment: I want to print at the first of every log file the version of my project which is defined in my .properties file.

Comment: Ok, well my answer below shows you how to include a header in every log file. Sourcing the _value_ of that header from your .properties file is another matter. Your application's logging subsystem (i.e. Logback) will likely be initialised **before** your .properties file is read so by the time the version is known to your application Logback will already be started. You may just have to include the version (hardcoded) in your logback.xml or supply it as a JVM parameter which Logback can read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a header to every file created by a `(Rolling)FileAppender`.

The following configuration will achieve this:

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>target/test.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <fileHeader>Your File Header ...</fileHeader>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </layout>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

With the above configuration the following text will appear before the first line written to the given file by any instance of the Logback subsystem:

```
Your File Header ...
```

Note: if your application is restarted (or Logback is re initialised within your application) then the `PatternLayout` will write that header again so you could end up with a log file having the following content:

```
Your File Header ...
11:11:59.589 [main] INFO  o.g.sandbox.logback.LogbackTest - hello!
Your File Header ...
11:12:12.352 [main] INFO  o.g.sandbox.logback.LogbackTest - hello!
```

To avoid this you could write your own Layout or Appender. Here's a simple example extending `FileAppender`:

```
public class FileAppenderWithHeader extends FileAppender {

    private String header;

    public String getHeader() {
        return header;
    }

    public void setHeader(String header) {
        this.header = header;
    }

    @Override
    public void openFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
        super.openFile(fileName);
        File activeFile = new File(getFile());
        if (activeFile.exists() && activeFile.isFile() && activeFile.length() == 0) {
            write((header + "\n").getBytes());
        }
    }

    private void write(byte[] byteArray) throws IOException {
        if (byteArray == null || byteArray.length == 0)
            return;

        lock.lock();
        try {
            super.getOutputStream().write(byteArray);
            if (super.isImmediateFlush()) {
                super.getOutputStream().flush();
            }
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

You would configure this like so:

```
<appender name="FILE" class="org.glytching.sandbox.logging.FileAppenderWithHeader">
    <file>target/test.log</file>
    <header>Your File Header ...</header>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
        </pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

And every file created by this appender would start with this line (regardless of how many times the appender is started/stopped):

```
Your File Header ...
```

Comment: I'm facing a problem with this solution. The Header is printed once after initialization, and when I add a listener and reconfigure it, it's printed one more time. So my Header is printed twice.what should I do?